# -2V LED indication with NTR1P02LT1G

Tags: led

I have implemented the attached circuit for -2V indication. LED D6A is turning ON by giving just VCC_5V(=+5V). LED is working independent of VCC_2VN(= **-2V**). Please correct me and suggest the proper circuit.

Srikanth Kacchu[image]

Comment: You have the FET body diode forward biased, and that provides a path for the LED current event when the FET is off.

Comment: Can you use the -2v rail?  Or put a pulling resistor on the input?  What exact criteria do you have for the turn on anyway.

Comment: @Chris Stratton, I am give -2V only at Gate input. Where do I place pulling resistor? I am giving -2V from external power supply by making it ON and OFF.